# Discrepancy with the same maven module having different versions of given dependency

Tags: java, maven

It's kind of hard to explain my problem with words, so I took a pic, which shows exactly what my problem is:

[image]

As you can see, I have 3 relevant modules, a global, genui and web.

genui depends on global and web depends on genui.

Directly, web doesn't depend on global, but through genui it obviously does.

As you can see, if I take a look at the hibernate version of web->genui->global, it is 5.2.14, but if I look at it from genui->global, it's 5.3.0.

There is not, and there have never been any versions of either of these modules other than 1.0-SNAPSHOT.

I tried cleaning, deleting the files from .m2/repository, and even tried purging the local repo completely, nothing worked. I have no idea where maven gets the 5.2.14 number, I don't remember ever putting that in. The version is received from a property in parent module.

I figured out that the problem is caused by the pom.xml of web module, more specifically this part:

```
<dependencyManagement>
...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
...
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: You probably need to exclude that repeated dependency from one of the spring ones... verify all your dependencies and look which are the ones that include hibernate. Check that you also have different versions for servlet-api.

Comment: yeah, I saw the servlet one too, but I chose not to mention it, so we can zero in on the problem. Thank you for the idea, I'd never think of this, but instead I just purged the whole element.

Comment: How can I accept this as a solution?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer. Modify it, accept it, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to exclude that repeated dependency from one of the spring ones... verify all your dependencies and look which are the ones that include hibernate. Check that you also have different versions for servlet-api.